# Finding the value of an infinite product

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

> Find the value of the product :
>   $$P=\sqrt{\frac12}\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12}}\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{\frac12}}}\ldots$$

This was asked in an exam yesterday, I still don't know how to solve this but the answer apparently is $\frac{2}{\pi}$

I have tried taking the logarithm of both sides to convert this into a summation and then tried to express it in the form of 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{r=0}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)$$
So that I can integrate it, however I'm not able to express it in this form.

Comment: Nice finds, @Hans !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that:
$$ f:x\mapsto\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{2}}$$
acts by mapping $\cos\theta$ into $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$. If we set $x_1=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, it follows that our product is given by:
$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}x_n = \prod_{n\geq 1}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right) $$
that is a telescopic product:
$$\prod_{n=1}^{N}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)=\prod_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}{2\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)}=\frac{1}{2^N \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{N+1}}\right)}.$$
By letting $N\to +\infty$, the claim $\prod_{n\geq 1}x_n = \frac{2}{\pi}$ follows. It is known as [Viète's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te's_formula).

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for the link too.